# Scrape site based on span text

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape only "MLB" scores from the following site:
www.scoresandodds.com/pgrid_20160628.html?sort=rot

A section of the HTML code looks like:

```
<div xmlns:dat="http://scoresandodds.com/dataset-main" class="section">
<div class="heading"><
span class="league">MLB</span>
<span class="date">06/28/2016</span>
</div><table cellpadding="0" summary="" cellspacing="0" border="0"><thead>
<tr><th class="first">Team</th><th>Pitcher</th><th>Open</th><th>Current</th><th>Runline</th><th>Scores</th><th>Notes</th>
</tr></thead><tbody><tr><td class="teamName">901 <a href="http://scoresandodds.com/statfeed/statfeed.php?page=MLB/MLBteam&amp;teamid=NY+METS&amp;season=">NEW YORK METS</a></td>
<td class="pitcher">(r) harvey, m</td>
<td class="line">8</td>
<td class="line">8.5o15</td>
<td class="line">+1.5(-200)</td>
<td class="score">0 Under 8.5</td>
```

My code starts with:

```
url = "http://www.scoresandodds.com/pgrid_"+date+".html?sort=rot"
soup =  BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url), 'html.parser')
scores = soup.find_all("span", {"class": "league"})

print(scores) 
[<span class="league">MLB</span>, <span class="league">WNBA</span>]
```

What it returns is great, but I am unclear how to only scrape the data for "MLB" scores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locate the `MLB` "label" and get the first following `table` only via [`find_next()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-next-and-find-next):

```
mlb_table = soup.find("span", class_="league", text="MLB").find_next("table")
```

Comment: Gorgeous - Thanks!